# Erlegen or erlegt?

Tags: verb-usage, verb-choice

These sentences appears in today's [DW Langsamer gesprochene Nachrichten](https://www.dw.com/de/27052021-langsam-gesprochene-nachrichten/a-57684650):

> Der Sohn deutscher Auswanderer sei bereits am Sonntag im Alter von 91 Jahren gestorben, teilte seine Familie mit. Sein Vater sei in seinem Studio im US-Bundesstaat Massachusetts einem Nierenversagen **erlegen**, sagte Sohn Rolf der "New York Times".

Is this a correct use of **erlegen**? Duden does allow it to mean, "to strike down", though it seems odd since it is apparently used in reference to hunting animals. But setting that aside, shouldn't it be **eledigt**?

Comment: You got the wrong word: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/erliegen

Comment: Dangerous false friend ;) "Das Nierenversagen hat ihn [erlegt|erledigt]" both show a severe lack of sense of reverence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an example of a word that tends to enter German dictionaries as two "similar" "separate" words when the likely protoindogerman root (often still visible in Classical Greek) had active, medium, and passive voice, with the medium voice implying reflexive (rather than transitive) involvement of the subject with itself.

You get "strong declension" for the "medium voice"/reflexive meaning then.

You have this with words like "hängen, hängte, gehängt" for transitive use and "hängen, hing, gehangen" for intransitive.  "legen, legte, gelegt" as opposed to "liegen, lag, gelegen".

In a similar vein there is "erliegen, erlag, erlegen" for succumbing (usually to something, genetive object) while "erlegen, erlegte, erlegt" is for killing something (accusative object), usually game.

Only the transitive verbs/forms can sensibly be used in the passive voice.

"erledigen, erledigte, erledigt" (the likely word you are alluding to) is unrelated and means "finishing (off)".  Not a good word in this context, either.

Comment: _erliegen_ (succombing) in German comes with a dative obect: _Er ist einem schweren Herzleiden erlegen_.

Comment: Das konnt' er nich' ab ...:-)

Answer (score 3):

Let me just give the 3 verbs that play a role here.

1. [erliegen](https://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/erliegen)

To succumb to ...

Use, as @guidot said, togther with a dative object "erliegen ... einer Krankheit oder einer Verletzung".

2. [erlegen](https://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/erlegen)

To hunt down, to slay. What a hunter does to their game.

3. [erledigen](https://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/erledigen)

To deal with, or to execute. Note that just like in English to execute can refer to a harmless task as well as to a kill, but the German use of "erledigen" for to kill is more like gangster slang ('false friend').

But in the above case, 1. is the correct translation.
See also conjugation table for [erliegen](https://dict.leo.org/pdf/flectionTable.pdf?kvz=4dkrADn71HeCbYC86wUP8lumz53RnXJXdziIUKuNxIdCy9CpG7CNU0tWWXp2a0JiVx8ewnvbpAbkLcUtHRLPkzuWKbuAPsMkEZ9_Ri8u4iEUnTUs2yL9BzfSf34WrVKTh47cFa39pibUPYBqytNuhIwHCMtwrRRCUI8eUdoY9UcyzIXvnFFN1X0Az73TLOUB0NxuVlvtpEeC-7UoHfQ904sWKf31qZk&lp=ende&lang=en). Accidentally, the Konjunktiv Perfekt of "erliegen" ("er sei erlegen") has the same writing as the infinitive of the verb "erlegen".

Answer (score -1):

I think **erlegen** is correct, since it is the passive form (Sein Vater sei *an* einem Nierenversagen erlegen)

Comment: [Erliegen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/erliegen) requires a dative object and does not combine well with the  preposition *an*.

Comment: ... and _sei ... erlegen_ is no passive but _Konjunktiv Perfekt Aktiv_ (Perfekt = _ist erlegen_, like _ist gestorben_; Konjunktiv Perfekt _sei erlegen, sei gestorben_)